# Where does the phrase ecchi sketchy one touchy come from?

Tags: japanese-language, toradora, kore-wa-zombie-desu-ka

In several anime, a character will yell this on despise to something perverted. It even shows up in non anime media like Yakuza Kiwami 2. What’s the origin of this phrase?

Comment: I've never heard of the 'sketchy one touchy', but 'ecchi' comes from the letter 'h' in 'hentai'. Japanese pronounce 'h' as 'ecchi'

Comment: Found a possible answer in another reddit post but it is in Japanese: https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/エッチスケッチワンタッチ Maybe someone who knows can translate this for you.

Answer (score 1):

My Japanese is not great, but the link supplied by W. Are, [https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/エッチスケッチワンタッチ](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%83%81) does give an explanation.

Apparently it's a phrase commonly used by school children in the 70's, but it's unknown where exactly the phrase comes from. The page lists several different theories, though my Japanese is not good enough to quite get all of the theories. One is that "touch" is what kids say when playing tag (instead of "tag, you're it"), another is there was a product by the company Glico called one touch curry. But at any rate, it's a phrase that caught on because of the sing-song, rhyming sort of sound to the phrase, and from what I gather from the article, similar to the kid nonsense sayings of western culture, like "circle-circle-dot-dot now I have a cootie shot."